# So,I made this simple C program to give output,so it is correct for positive and zero integer values but it is coming wrong for negative even and odd

Tags: c, if-statement

How to get out of this first if else construct because when I input Negative values,because the condition here is checked and then it goes to the last else statement where this just prints zero

```
 #include<stdio.h>
      int main() {
         int x;
      scanf("%d", &x);

 if(x>0)
{

    printf("Positive");
    {
        if(x%2==0)
        {

            printf("Even");

        }
        else
        {

            printf("Odd");
        }

    }
```

I want this to be executed when I input negative values,but I'm unable to do so

```
    if(x<0)
    {
            
 printf("Negative");

        {

            if(x%2==0) {

                printf("Even");

            }
            else {

                printf("Odd");

            }


        }


    }

}

else {

    printf("Zero");

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code and show your input, expected and actual outputs.

Comment: Also read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: If you format and indent your code, the problem will become apparent.

Comment: Any decent editor should show you hat the matching `{` for your `}else` is right after `if(x>0)`. Everything in between is part of that first `if`

Comment: You should use `else if (x < 0)`. Otherwise the last `else` is only attached to the second `if`.

Comment: @Barmar that would only work if that `if` wasn't enclosed within the `if (x < 0)` part.

Comment: @FlintStone If you've got a compiler, you can probably get a code editor for your phone. Might be worth the trouble finding out. In addition to GUI editors, `nano`, `emacs`, `vim`, are command-line editors that will help you retain formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reindent your code you will find strange `{` like the one after  `printf("Positive");`

Juste removing this strange `{` and fixing your coding style will be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if ( x > 0 ) {
        printf("Positive");
        if ( x % 2 == 0 ) {
            printf("Even");
            
        } else {
            printf("Odd");
        }
    } else if( x < 0 ) {
        printf("Negative");
        if( x % 2 == 0 ) {
            printf("Even");
        } else {
            printf("Odd");
        }
    }   
    else {
        printf("Zero");
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

easier to read, easier to debug

Comment: Thanks for actually helping me out,yes I know I don't have a decent editor because I am learning to code on a phone due to non availability of a pc.That's why the formatting isn't upto what the community asks for and hence the downvotes.

Comment: @FlintStone learning to code on a phone (?!). Good luck with that. First thing to do: get yourself a PC. Any cheap PC/laptop will do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is an incorrect nesting of compound statements.

I can suggest the following solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { Negative = -1, Zero = 0, Positive = 1};

    printf( "Enter a number: " );
    
    int x = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &x );

    int sign = ( 0 < x ) - ( x < 0 );

    switch (sign)
    {
    case Negative:
        printf( "Negative " );
        break;
    case Zero:
        puts( "Zero" );
        break;
    case Positive:
        printf( "Positive " );
        break;
    }

    if (sign != 0)
    {
        puts( x % 2 == 0 ? "even." : "odd." );
    }
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a number: 10
Positive even.
```

Comment: Thanks.Though I'm not aware of enums I'll make sure to brush up my knowledge about it.